# To find the MIN value in an array of 3 - MASM

Tags: assembly

Can someone help me figure out why this code isn't working?  I received an error on the 3 lines with the compare instructions.  This is for class and I have to teach myself basically, so any help would be appreciated.  This assignment is for a chapter on passing values and analyzing the stack.

```
; procedure to compute the minimum of 3 DWORD values
; The MIN is calculated, returned in eax, and displayed.
; Other registers are unchanged.

.386            ; assembler use 80386 instructions
.MODEL  FLAT    ; use modern standard memory model 

ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD

INCLUDE io.h    ; header file for input/output

cr      EQU     0dh     ; carriage return
Lf      EQU     0ah     ; line feed

.STACK  4096    ; reserve 4096-byte stack

.DATA   ; reserve storage for data

num1    DWORD   0
num2    DWORD   0
num3    DWORD   0

directions  BYTE     cr, Lf, 'Please enter 3 numbers.', cr, Lf
            BYTE     'This program will then report the minimum',cr,Lf, 0
numlabel    BYTE        cr,Lf,Lf, 'The MIN is:  '
minValue    BYTE     16 DUP (?), cr,Lf,0    

.CODE   ; program code

MIN3  PROC   NEAR32

    push    ebp         ; save base pointer
    mov     ebp,esp     ; copy stack pointer
    push    ebx         ; save registers
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    cmp     num1, num2
    jg      second
    cmp     num1, num3
    jg      second
    mov     eax, num1
    jmp     retpop

second:
    cmp     num2, num3
    jg      third
    mov     eax, num2
    jmp     retpop

third:
    mov     eax, num3
    jmp     retpop

retpop: 
    pop     edx         ; restore registers
    pop     ecx 
    pop     ebx          
    pop     ebp         ; restore base pointer
    ret                 ; return

MIN3  ENDP

_start:     ; program entry point

    output  directions      ; display directions
    input   minValue,16     ; get number
    atod    minValue        ; convert to integer
    mov     num1, eax
    input   minValue,16     ; get number
    atod    minValue        ; convert to integer
    mov     num2, eax
    input   minValue,16     ; get number
    atod    minValue        ; convert to integer
    mov     num3, eax

    call   MIN3             ; find minimum value, ret eax

    dtoa    minValue, eax
    output  numlabel


INVOKE ExitProcess, 0   ; exit with return code 0
PUBLIC _start           
END
```

Comment: Which error are you getting on which instructions exactly?

Comment: I noticed you tried to thank Jester by posting your thanks as an answer (which, has been deleted because it wasn't an answer). The right way to thank a user for helping you would be to "upvote" and "accept" their answer. To "upvote", click on the upward-pointing arrow next to their answer; and to "accept", click on the check-mark next to their question. For a picture of these icons, see the first section of http://stackoverflow.com/tour See also [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/139866)

Answer (score 3):

`x86` has no version of the `cmp` instruction that supports 2 memory operands. As such, `cmp num1, num2` is invalid, you should load one of them into a register and use that for the comparison, for example:

```
mov edx, num1
cmp edx, num2
```

You should pay attention to what the assembler is trying to tell you through the error message and also have the instruction set reference handy.